# Pinning the bottom cell of a tableview on rotation

Tags: ios, uitableview, screen-rotation

Just like in Telegram or Whatsapp, when the device rotates, the bottom cell should stay anchored to the bottom of the screen.

However, when I rotate my device, the top cell is being anchored and stays foot. Couldn't find any solution online.

Here is how I want a rotation to look like:

[image]

Comment: Added more appropriate tags.